# Does Google Cloud Dataflow supports OpenJDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

It would be good if any one knows, does Google Cloud Dataflow supports OpenJDK?

Comment: You should be able to run Beam pipelines on OpenJDK

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   Could you please give some sample code or any reference to implement Beam pipeline with OpenJDK.

Comment: I think if we look here ... https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/  we find that the recipe calls for "a" JDK in place.  If your JDK is OpenJDK 8 you should then be able to run the rest of the recipe.  As for Google Dataflow as the runner, my guess is that you don't have a choice over which JDK runs your pipeline flow as the execution of the Beam pipeline is the service that Google provides.

Comment: Can confirm: I ran this sample https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven using OpenJDK which ships with Unity. However, the sample specifically tells you to install Oracle's JDK version 8.